# How to add on click event in datatables buttons like excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'LicenseDetails_'+(++download_file_counter)+'_'+today,            
    text: 'Excel',
    exportOptions: {
      modifier: {
        page: 'current'                         
      }
    }
  }
]
```

On click of excel button download file counter should increment. Please tell me where to add onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will resolve the your issue.

```
$(".buttons-excel").on('click',function(){

//Do some operations here.
});
```

If you have any doubts please comment